# ASP.Net Client Side Modal Progress Indicator

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I've tried implementing [this example](http://weblogs.asp.net/guillermo/archive/2008/02/24/ajax-how-to-create-a-quot-processing-quot-modal-window-using-updateprogress-and-modalpopup-asp-net-ajax-controls.aspx), but the progress never displays.  My page doesn't include any UpdatePanels or anything, could that be why?

In my page declaration I've added:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>
```

Inside the head element I've added:

```
<script src="Scripts/jsUpdateProgress.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Immediately inside of my form tag I've added:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:Panel ID="panelUpdateProgress" runat="server" CssClass="updateProgress">
    <asp:UpdateProgress runat="server" ID="UpdateProg1" DisplayAfter="0">
        <ProgressTemplate>
            <div style="position:relative; top:30%; text-align: center;">
                <img src="Processing.gif" style="vertical-align: middle" alt="Processing"/>
                  Processing...
            </div>
        </ProgressTemplate>
    </asp:UpdateProgress>
</asp:Panel>
<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender runat="server" ID="ModalProgress" TargetControlID="panelUpdateProgress" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" PopupControlID="panelUpdateProgress"/>
```

Immediately following end form tag I've added:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(beginReq);
        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(endReq);
        var ModelProgress = '<%= ModalProgress.ClientID %>';
        function beginReq(sender, args) {
            $find(ModalProgress).show();
        }            
        function endReq(sender, args) {
            $find(ModalProgress).hide();
        }
</script>
```

The button I expect to cause the progress to show:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="submit" CssClass="multiViewTab" Text="Submit"/>
```

That button definitely posts back because in my form tag I have:

```
onsubmit="return validateForm()"
```

And validateForm runs.  validateForm also kicks off the submitForm function if the form is valid, and this contains a JQuery call to AJAX invoking a web service.

Take 2:

Much simpler and pure AJAX, but still doesn't work.

```
 </form>
 <script type='javascript'>
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').append('<div id="ajaxBusy"><p><img src="Processing.gif"></p></div>');
    $('#ajaxBusy').css("updateProgress");
  });

  $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
            $('#ajaxBusy').css("z-index", 2);
        }).ajaxStop(function () {
            $('#ajaxBusy').css("z-index", -1);
        });
```

I am using z-index because I have a makeshift "wizard" which in essence shows/hides divs using z-index and the progress div wouldn't show up if I didn't change the z-index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to MSDN, the `UpdateProgress` provides feedback when contents of an `UpdatePanel` are updated.

> My page doesn't include any UpdatePanels or anything, could that be
>   why?

In short, yes.

Source: [UpdateProgress Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updateprogress.aspx)

The above link has a nice example.

Comment: Makes sense.  Thanks.  Found another example using pure AJAX, but still no luck.  I will update my post with that.

Comment: I think I know why that one doesn't work either now.  The AJAX calls to the web service are in a loop.  So also tried ajaxComplete.  Either ajaxStart is never firing or is immediately getting cancelled upon the first completion of the loop.

Comment: Well, keep in mind that the UpdateProgress is only useful if you are doing a partial postback (UpdatePanel).  Calling a web method via ajax doesn't necessarily perform a partial postback which is probably what you are experiencing.  I would imagine that your Take 2 example would work however...though, in combination with your z-index tweaks, I would also make it visible or hidden (just in case your z-index is the issue - which I would double check if I were you): `$('#element').show()` or `$('#element').hide()`

Comment: Thanks.  I think the issue is that the AJAX is in a loop.  When I toggle z-index in the console, it behaves exactly how I want.  It just either isn't triggering in the ajaxStart or because it is in a loop it is immediately then running the ajaxStop or ajaxComplete that then hides it again after the first loop.

Comment: I've confirmed that ajaxStart does trigger.  Now the progress div never hides.

Comment: Ok. The issue is that i set the ajax calls to async=false.  I removed that and the progress div shows and hides correctly.  thanks for your help.

Comment: Excellent job!  Another bug bites the dust!